# Move point one meter to the right

Tags: openlayers

I have a feature with a point geometry at position x,y on a map with projection `EPSG:900913`. I want to move the point 1 meter to the right.

```
function movePoint(coordinate) {
 let point = new ol.geom.Point(coordinate);
 // do something that moves the point 1m to the right.

}
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: `point.translate(1, 0)`  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Point-Point.html#translate

Comment: Please do **not** ever use EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) to carry out any sort of distance related analysis. The longitude (X) axis is distorted to infinity as you move north or south of the Equator.

Comment: If you want to move point by real meters, not projection units, I would use `turf.destination` method from [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/docs/#destination) library.